# Image behind drop down menu issue HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the drop down menu stay top right with the image behind it if anyone could help would be greatly appreciated i tried using z-index but that didn't work out for me !
( using a img off google so u guys can see what im talking about! )

```css
/* Drop Down Menu */

.navClass {
 z-index: 999;
 float: right;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}

.navClass > ul {
 background-color: #5E5D5D;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navClass > ul > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 25px;
 position: relative;
}

.navClass > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

ul.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #383838;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 125px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 0pc;
 margin-left: -25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 opacity: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navClass li:hover .sub-menu {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.navClass ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D8D8D8;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

/* Background */

/* ZeeFro */
.zeefro {   
 z-index: -1;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>STREAMER // DESIGNER // YOUTUBER</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="bg-Main">
<img src="">
</nav>

<nav class="zeefro">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d-zKJCKsoWw/maxresdefault.jpg" text-align: center; >
</nav>

<nav class="navClass">

<ul>

 <li><a href="">Contact Me</li></a>

 <li><a href="">Home</li></a>
 <li><a href="">About Me</li></a>
 <li><a href="">Portfolio

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Logos</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Banners</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Shop

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Graphics</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Merch</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Social Media

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
  <li><a href="">All</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>
 
</ul>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Either i did something wrong within the z-index unless i don't know whats happening :P

Kind regards 
ZeFrolity

Comment: `position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `position: absolute` to the div with background.

but
if a image is for background, you will usually want to use css `background-image` attribute instead of `<img>` tag.

you will also only need one nav tag only

```css
/* Drop Down Menu */

.navClass {
 z-index: 999;
 float: right;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}

.navClass > ul {
 background-color: #5E5D5D;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navClass > ul > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 25px;
 position: relative;
}

.navClass > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

ul.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #383838;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 125px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 0pc;
 margin-left: -25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 opacity: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navClass li:hover .sub-menu {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.navClass ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D8D8D8;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

/* Background */

/* ZeeFro */
.zeefro {   
 z-index: -1;
 text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d-zKJCKsoWw/maxresdefault.jpg")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>STREAMER // DESIGNER // YOUTUBER</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>



<div class="zeefro">
</div>

<nav class="navClass">

<ul>

 <li><a href="">Contact Me</li></a>

 <li><a href="">Home</li></a>
 <li><a href="">About Me</li></a>
 <li><a href="">Portfolio

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Logos</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Banners</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Shop

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Graphics</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Merch</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Social Media

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
  <li><a href="">All</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>
 
</ul>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position the menu instead. I also removed the margin from `body`.

```css
/* Drop Down Menu */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navClass {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; right: 0;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}

.navClass > ul {
 background-color: #5E5D5D;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navClass > ul > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 25px;
 position: relative;
}

.navClass > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

ul.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #383838;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 125px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 0pc;
 margin-left: -25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 opacity: 0;
}

ul.sub-menu li {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navClass li:hover .sub-menu {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.navClass ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #D8D8D8;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
 background-color: #383838;
}

/* Background */

/* ZeeFro */
.zeefro {   
 z-index: -1;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>STREAMER // DESIGNER // YOUTUBER</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="bg-Main">
<img src="">
</nav>

<nav class="zeefro">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d-zKJCKsoWw/maxresdefault.jpg" text-align: center; >
</nav>

<nav class="navClass">

<ul>

 <li><a href="">Contact Me</li></a>

 <li><a href="">Home</li></a>
 <li><a href="">About Me</li></a>
 <li><a href="">Portfolio

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Logos</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Banners</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Shop

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Graphics</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Merch</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="">Social Media

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="">Twitch</li></a>
  <li><a href="">Youtube</li></a>
  <li><a href="">All</li></a>
 </ul>

 </li>
 
</ul>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like he wants the image for background, if that is true it is better to set absolute the background, otherwise you would need to set every element absolute.

Comment: @Kossel it's a solution and since OP only wants the menu positioned, it's the same amount of work as positioning `background`.

Comment: no i didnt want it for a background but this will help in the future when i add another bg this is for a small img in the middle which will have my name and a background behind tht also thank you!